# Which class constructor is called when we try to create a primitive array object using 'new'

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, new-operator

Which constructor is called when we try to do the follow:

`int[] arr = new int[10];`

From what I understand, for every single time that we use the keyword `new`, an `object` is created inside the *Heap*, using the constructor of the respective class, and its address is returned back to the reference variable.

My question is; Since Boolean, byte, short, character, int.... are all primitives and don't have a built in class or a constructor (at least I couldn't find one inside the src.zip),

```
boolean[] b = new boolean[10];
byte[] by = new byte[10];
short[] s = new short[10];
char[] ch = new char[10];
int[] i = new int[10];
long[] l = new long[10];
float[] f = new float[10];
double[] d = new double[10];
```

What object is returned when we try to create their array using `new` and how is that object created?

Comment: It is not an instance of a class, but of an array. An array is a built-in data structure and does not provide a constructor.

Comment: @f1sh could you please provide me with any kind of documentation for your answer

Answer (score 1):

An [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) *is* an object in Java.

The values in an array of primitives are initialized to their respective default value (e.g. 0 for int, 0.0 for double, etc.)

The values in an array of Objects are initialized to point to null references until you assign them.

Comment: using constructor from which class?

Comment: Did you not read the previous comments?

Comment: I did, could you please link me any kid of documentation on the same?

Comment: Someone else already did, if I recall correctly.

Comment: i don't see it, could you please paste it here?

Comment: Please click on the duplicate link above.  There's a good explanation there.